# Best Way To Handle Removing Records in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I have a lot of entities that have ManyToOne and OneToMany associations in Symfony2. As all know if you remove a record and it doesnt set a null value on the association in the other tables, things start to go haywire. So, what is the best way in Symfony2 to handle setting the value as null in other tables when a record is removed in Symfony2?

What do I need to set in my entities to ensure it persists across all associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can manually set `ON DELETE` behavior for the FK by using **onDelete** property for the [joinColumn](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn) annotation in your entity:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="SomeEntity")
 * @JoinColumn(name="some_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
 */
private $someEntity;
```

Secondly, you always can implement event listener for the entity removing event.  For example:

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if (!$entity instanceof SomeEntity) {
        return;
    }

    // Here you can do whatever you want before
    // entity record is removed from the DB.
 }
```

You can read about the doctrine event system using following links:

- [Doctrine events (official manual)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html)
- [How to Register Doctrine Event Listeners and Subscribers (Symfony2 cookbook)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

The difference between them is that the first method works on the database layer. In other words, it would work even if you delete record using raw sql query in the console. Second one is more powerfull because you can also run any php code when entity is removed (for example you can send emails, etc.) but it will *only* be fired if record is removed via doctrine.